# How to return a C array modified with MIPS Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to change an array initialized in a C function, that calls an assembly function to modify it, like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void change_table(int* array, int dim, int lim);

    int main(){
        int dim = 6;
        int array[] = {1000, 200, 900, 870, 500, 5000};
        int res;
        change_table(array, dim, 850);
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < dim; i++)
             printf("index %d = %d\n", i, array[i]);

        return 0;
    }
```

And here is the assembly function:

```
    .data
    .text
    .globl change_table
    addi $t2, $0, 0

    change_table:
        beq $t2, $a1, exit
        lbu $t0, 0($a0)
        slt $t1, $t0, $a2
        beq $t1, 1, change
        return:
        sb $a0, 0($t0)
        addi $a0, $a0, 1
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j main

    change:
        ori $t0, $t0, 0xf
        j return

    exit:
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

And that's my question: How do I return it?, or do I have to return it?

Comment: You don't have to return it. Just like in C. You modify the elements through the pointer, and that's that.

Comment: That's what I thought but it is not working anyway.

Comment: How are you compiling/linking the two source code together? I have done this for ARM assembly but on a ARM processor (RPi) where gcc is already ported for ARM assembly.